# Changing things from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

What is the easiest way to take something out of an vector and changes its values? This isn't working the way I expected.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
someType s = list.at(i);
s.x = 10;
s.y = 20;
s.z = 30;
}
```

However, when I go to print out the x,y,z of that someType s, it doesn't give me what I expect. Sorry I am mixing up Java and C++.

Comment: What is this "arraylist?"  Do you mean a `std::vector`?

Comment: I expect any reader/maintainer to get confused when they find out that the `list` is a `vector`!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
someType s = list.at(i);
```

You are making a *copy* of the element at index `i`.  In C++, if you want a reference to something, you need to explicitly state that you want a reference:

```
someType& s = list.at(i);
     // ^ I'm a reference
```

As it is written now, you only manipulate the copy that you make, not the object in the container.

Answer (score 4):

There's no "ArrayList" in standard C++ library. I'm guessing you are using `std::vector`, `std::vector<someType>` to be exact.

STL containers store objects *by value*. The first line within that loop body invokes `someType`'s *[copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor)*, so you end up with a *copy* of the object. That copy is [automatically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), i.e. it's on the stack. You update the copy and then it goes out of scope and is [destructed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) at the end of the iteration. The original object held in the vector is unchanged.

#### Edit:

And of course I forgot to make the final point - *use a reference* (see James' answer, which you should probably accept).

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are copying the values.
How is defined the list ? a list of objects or a list of pointers to objects?
Make sure to use the & as "reference" to the list item.

```
T& s = list.at(i);
s.x = 0;
s.y = 1;
```

Comment: They are an vector of objects. I want to be able to change the items in the list without always having to have use list.at(i).x = 10, since its very long.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying the values; each object is copied using its [default] copy-constructor.

I you want to refer to the elements of the list more easily, you should use `reference`s:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
someType& s = list.at(i);
//      ^ This is a reference
s.x = 10;
s.y = 20;
s.z = 30;
}
```

You can think about this reference just as an "alias" to an element of the list.